# How do I report incorrect information in the meteor docs?

Tags: meteor

There's some misleading information in the Meteor docs in the Accounts section, specifically:

> Either a string interpreted as a username or an email; or an object with a single key: email, username or **`id`**.

`id` is not a valid parameter, which mislead me and wasted my time until I checked the source code itself:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L14

Without wanting to create a branch, then pull request, how do I notify the Meteor team of this misleading parameter description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think this is a [account-password issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/labels/Project%3AAccounts%3APassword), just create a [new issue on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues), explaining the error.